# How do I call a module repeatedly in Verilog, in sync with a clock?

Tags: fpga, verilog, clock, hdl

What I intend to do is basically cycle through a LUT created in a second module, by instantiating it in the first. Additionally, I need to call the instantiation in sync with the clock.

The basic idea is this following LUT:

```
module lut_new(
    input clk, rst, address,
    output reg [15:0] data
    );
    
    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if(rst) begin data<=0; end
    else begin
    case(address)
    8'b00000000: data<=16'b0000000000000000;
    8'b00000001: data<=0.4125;
    8'b00000010: data<=0.825;
    8'b00000011: data<=1.2375;
    8'b00000100: data<=1.65;
    8'b00000101: data<=2.0625;
    8'b00000110: data<=2.475;
    8'b00000111: data<=2.8875;
    endcase
    end
   end
endmodule
```

I need to call it to get the data individually for each address. The top module is basically displaying this data into the output serially. Now what I can do is output it serially, not an issue.

My problem:
I want to cycle through the LUT with the help of clock, but I cannot call a module within the always block. How do I solve this issue?
More detail: The information is of 16 bits, so I need to send each value bit by bit, and then after each transmission is over, after a short span of time (predefined), I wish to move to the next address. Also, I am using a clock divider for output too.

Following is part of the top module:

```
module timing(
    input clk, rst,
    output reg data, 
    output reg sync,
    output reg oclk
    );
    

    reg [6:0]f =0;
    reg x=0;
    reg [6:0] count = 7'b0;
    reg [15:0] value;
    reg [7:0] address=8'b0;
    lut_new ff1 (clk, rst, address, value); // How do I call this in sync with clock.
    
    
    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
        if(rst) begin
            count <=1'b0; 
            sync<=1'b0; 
            data<=1'b0; 
            oclk<=1'b0; 
            f<=1'b0; 
        end
        else begin 
            case(count)
                7'b0000000: begin oclk<=1; count<=count+1; sync<=1; f<=count+4; data<=0; end
                7'b0000001: begin oclk<=1; count<=count+1; sync<=1; f<=f/4; data<=0; end
                7'b0000010: begin oclk<=0; count<=count+1; sync<=1; f<=f-1; end
                7'b0000011: begin oclk<=0; count<=count+1; sync<=1;  end
                7'b0000100: begin oclk<=1; count<=count+1; sync<=0; data<= x? value[f]: value1[f]; f<=count+4; end
                7'b0000101: begin oclk<=1; count<=count+1; sync<=0; f<=f/4; end
                .
                .
                .
                7'b1000100: begin oclk<=1; count<=7'b0000001; sync<=1; data<=0; x<=~x;end
            endcase
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, apart from your basic question about calling a module repeatedly in Verilog, there are alot of mistakes in your code:

1. `address` is not being driven by any logic.
2. `value1` is not declared anywhere in timing module.
3. lut_new module has `address` input but it is only 1-bit. you need to change it to 8-bit.
4. In lut_new module, you cannot define float points value as you have defined.

Updated lut_new module:

```
module lut_new(
    input clk, rst, 
    input [7:0] address,
    output reg [15:0] data
);

    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
        if (rst) begin
            data <= 16'b0;
        end
        else begin
            case(address)
                8'b00000000: data <= 16'b0000000000000000;
                8'b00000001: data <= 16'b0010100000000000; // Replace 0.4125 with its fixed-point representation
                8'b00000010: data <= 16'b0101000000000000; // Replace 0.825 with its fixed-point representation
                // Add other cases for each address
                // ...
                default: data <= 16'b0; // Default case if address is not matched
            endcase
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Secondly, Yes, this is correct that a module cannot be called within an always block.
The solution is pretty simple. Just instantiate the module once (as you have already done) and periodically (as per requirement) keep changing the `address` register and, as a result, the corresponding `value` will be automatically updated after one clock cycle. Here is the updated code for the `timing` module:

```
module timing(
    input clk, rst,
    output reg data, 
    output reg sync,
    output reg oclk
);

    reg [7:0] address = 8'b0;
    reg [15:0] value;
    lut_new ff1 (.clk(clk), .rst(rst), .address(address), .data(value));

    reg [6:0] f = 7'b0;
    reg x = 1'b0;
    reg [6:0] count = 7'b0;

    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
        if (rst) begin
            count <= 1'b0; sync <= 1'b0; data <= 1'b0; oclk <= 1'b0; f <= 7'b0; 
        end
        else begin 
            case(count)
                7'b0000000: begin
                    oclk <= 1;
                    count <= count + 1;
                    sync <= 1;
                    f <= count + 4;
                    data <= 0;
                end

                7'b0000001: begin
                    oclk <= 1;
                    count <= count + 1;
                    sync <= 1;
                    f <= f/4;
                    data <= 0;
                end

                7'b0000010: begin
                    oclk <= 0;
                    count <= count + 1;
                    sync <= 1;
                    f <= f - 1;
                end

                7'b0000011: begin
                    oclk <= 0;
                    count <= count + 1;
                    sync <= 1;
                end

                7'b0000100: begin
                    oclk <= 1;
                    count <= count + 1;
                    sync <= 0;
                    data <= x ? value[f] : value1[f];
                    f <= count + 4;
                end

                7'b0000101: begin
                    oclk <= 1;
                    count <= count + 1;
                    sync <= 0;
                    f <= f/4;
                end

                // Other cases...

                7'b1000100: begin
                    oclk <= 1;
                    count <= 7'b0000001;
                    sync <= 1;
                    data <= 0;
                    x <= ~x;
                    address <= address + 1; // Increment address for the next cycle
                end
            endcase
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My main mistake was not defining the inputs properly (address), that is what I had missed.

Comment: I have a question though. You said "data <= x ? value[f] : value1[f];" doesn't work. But it did, for me, when I had previously used value1 as well, to switch between outputs of FFFF and 0000. It worked in simulation as well as oscilloscope. I can attach an image too, in the post if necessary.

Comment: Which simulation tool are you using?

Comment: Xilinx Vivado 2018

Comment: Yes you are correct. There is no issue with that. I will update the answer. I confused it with another problem. We cannot have variable length indexing i.e. `data <= value[a:b];`, if `a` and `b` are both variables then it will give an error.

Comment: but still you have to declare `value1`.

Comment: Yes, I had declared it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151197/discussion-between-mahesh-namboodiri-and-im-groot).